# Cycle through multiple rows to put a variable into an API call

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to automate an API call using Excel Power Query and VBA. I got this working through recording the macro and tweaking it.

This calls the API, with a specified targetId and ScanId, and my auth key:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="scan-result", Formula:= "let" & Chr(10) & _
  "    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(""https://api.mcafeesecure.com/api/v1/scan-result.json?**targetId**=12345&**scanId**=aasdhgfdhgfaksdfgdhajsdfgdha"", [Headers=[#""x-apikey""=""mykeyhere""]]))," & _
  Chr(10) & "    scan = Source[scan]," & Chr(10) & "    #""Converted to Table"" = Record.ToTable(scan)," 
  '[etc]
```

This works if I specify the target and scan ids manually in each call.

**BUT** I need the targetId and ScanId to be variables, which are found in my tab "Scan Summary" in columns A and D respectively. 
I need VBA to cycle through all the rows in "Scan Summary" table - query A2 and D2 and output to a table, then A3 & D3, etc.

UPDATE:
I have a loop working, but the values of TargetID and ScanID aren't being parsed into the API call.

The error from Power query is:

> = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://api.mcafeesecure.com/api/v1/scan-result.json?targetId=" & TargetID & "&scanId=" & ScanID, [Headers=[#"x-apikey"="mykeygoeshere"]]))
>   Expression.Error: The name 'TargetID' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's spelled correctly

When I looked at the query, I thought I'd have the requisite targetID/ScanId in there, but instead I just have the words.

**VBA code:**

```
Dim TargetID As String
Dim ScanID As String
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To 2

    TargetID = Sheets("Scan Summary").Cells(i, 1).Value
    ScanID = Sheets("Scan Summary").Cells(i, 4).Value

    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="scan-result", Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(""https://api.mcafeesecure.com/api/v1/scan-result.json?targetId="" & TargetID & ""&scanId="" & ScanID, [Headers=[#""x-apikey""=""mykeygoeshere""]]))," & Chr(10) & "    scan = Source[scan]," & Chr(10) & "    #""Converted to Table"" = Record.ToTable(scan)," & Chr(10) & "    #""Transposed Table"" = Table.Transpose(#""Converted to Tabl" & _
    "e"")," & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#""Transposed Table"", [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Promoted Headers"",{{""dateTime"", type datetime}, {""targetId"", Int64.Type}, {""scanId"", type text}, {""vulns"", type any}, {""sevCountInfo"", type any}, {""sevCountVuln"", type any}, {""ports"", type any}}" & _
    ")," & Chr(10) & "    #""Expanded vulns"" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#""Changed Type"", ""vulns"")," & Chr(10) & "    #""Expanded vulns1"" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#""Expanded vulns"", ""vulns"", {""severity"", ""protocol"", ""vulnId"", ""first_found_date"", ""port"", ""pci""}, {""vulns.severity"", ""vulns.protocol"", ""vulns.vulnId"", ""vulns.first_found_date"", ""vulns.port"", ""vulns.pci""})" & _
    "," & Chr(10) & "    #""Reordered Columns"" = Table.ReorderColumns(#""Expanded vulns1"",{""dateTime"", ""targetId"", ""scanId"", ""vulns.vulnId"", ""vulns.severity"", ""vulns.protocol"", ""vulns.first_found_date"", ""vulns.port"", ""vulns.pci"", ""sevCountInfo"", ""sevCountVuln"", ""ports""})," & Chr(10) & "    #""Removed Columns"" = Table.RemoveColumns(#""Reordered Columns"",{""sevCountInfo""," & _
    " ""sevCountVuln"", ""ports""})" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(10) & "    #""Removed Columns"""

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=scan-result;Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [scan-result]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

Comment: Becky it is a simple for loop where you need to split a string and join them using `&` and variables. For Example `Sid123Rout456` can be written as `"Sid" & "123" & "Rout" & "456"` which can be further changed to `"Sid" & SOMEVARIABLE & "Rout" & SOMEVARIABLE`. Give it a try and if you get stuck, post the code you tried and we will take it from there

Comment: Hi Siddharth - I don't know how to write a loop ... (sorry!) I've gotten as far as specifying my variables: 

`Dim targetID As Integer
Dim ScanID As String
Dim i As Integer`

and I understand that I could use these as follows: 
`""https://api.mcafeesecure.com/api/v1/scan-result.json?TargetId=" & targetID & "&scanId=" & ScanID""`

But don't know how to set the variables in the first instance and then make it iterate through each row...

Comment: I would recommend googling on how to write a For Loop. I doubt anyone would give you the code in a platter unless someone wants to score points :D If you do not show any efforts then this question will end up being closed... I would also recommending seeing [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I can do this small thing for you :) Check [THIS](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html) out.... This will show you how to loop through the excel cells... Search Google for `for loop to loop through excel cells` and you will see lot of examples

Comment: @SiddharthRout Have updated it (thanks for the links) - I've got the loop working and variables set etc, but the values aren't being parsed into the API call - just the name of the variable... help?

Comment: I posted an answer. See if that helps?

Comment: BTW I used the original string and not the new one. If you want me to use that then post the extact string here without changing anything

Answer (score 1):

FWIW:
I found it a lot easier to code excel vba once I started defining proper objects, rather than working with 'active' anything.

As an example:

You have a  list of things you'd like to do with variables.

```
Dim wb as excel.workbook
Dim wsScanList as excel.worksheet
Let's say that you have your variable list in columns A and B, - no empty rows.
dim CurRow as long
dim Var1 as string (call it what you like)
dim Var2 as long


 and so on defining all your variables and object.
set wb = ThisWorkBook
set ws= wb.worksheets("Scan Summary")
CurRow = 2 (assuming that you have headers in row 1)
do until isempty(ws.Range("A" & CurRow))
    Var1 = ws.Range("A & CurRow)
    Var2 = ws.range("B" & Currow)
   now do whatever it is you need to do with the two variables
CurRow = CurRow + 1
Loop.
```

That should get you working with objects and doing a loop. The problem with Active anything is that what Excel thinks is active, may not be what you think it is

Using this structure allows you to add more replications without changing the code.

Your problem with variables COULD be to do with & and ""

Code like this

```
"do something with Var1 and Var2" won't work

"do something with '" & Var1 & "' and " & Var2    May well do.
```

Note the use of an apostrophe around Var1 (a string) , but not Var2 (a number) also the spaces after with, and around and.

This should work unless Var1 has an apostrophe in it (Like the name O'Grady.)

Hope that's enough of a clue to help

If you're working with several sheets in the same workbook, assign an object to each sheet.

Example you may have the list in one sheet, and want to put the result in another.

```
Set wsDriver as wb.worksheets("Scan List")
Set wsSrc = wb.worksheets("SourceData")
Set wsDest = anotherworkbook.worksheets("December Output")
```

wsDriver identifies something in common,  maybe a list of customers data.

wsSrc will contain the data you need to do something with,

wsData could be the output into a completely different excel file.

But once you have those object defined, you can SEE which sheet you're working with as you code, and it becomes a lot easier to nest Loops, and to follow the code ((IMO)

In most cases it doesn't matter what Excel thinks is 'active', which means that when debugging, you can pause the code and look as the sheets without worry.

Answer (score 0):

> @SiddharthRout Have updated it (thanks for the links) - I've got the loop working and variables set etc, but the values aren't being parsed into the API call - just the name of the variable

The way you constructed the string, the variable ended up behaving like a string rather than a variable.

Is this what you are trying? (**UNTESTED**)

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="scan-result", Formula:= _
"let" & Chr(10) & _
"    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(""https://api.mcafeesecure.com/api/v1/scan-result.json?targetId=" & _
TargetID & _
"scanId=" & _
ScanID & Chr(34) & _
", [Headers=[#""x-apikey""=""mykeyhere""]]))," & _
Chr(10) & _
"    scan = Source[scan]," & Chr(10) & _
"    #""Converted to Table"" = Record.ToTable(scan),"
```

Comment: Edit: I'm now getting the message on  `TargetID & _` : Compile error: Expected: end of statement

Comment: See my comment below your question :) Can you provide the exact string for `Formula:`. i.e with the values in it. I will create it from that.